# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^2.4^2\cdots{(2n)}^2}{3^2.5^2.\cdots {(2n+1)}^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to check the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^2.4^2\cdots{(2n)}^2}{3^2.5^2.\cdots {(2n+1)}^2}?$$ I tried by Ratio Test which fails as limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is equal to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.  Then how to check its convergence?

Comment: Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Hint: express your product using a ratio of squares of Gamma functions and use Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

\begin{align*}
&\frac{2^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdots {(2n)}^2}{3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdots {(2n+1)}^2} \\
&= \frac{2^2}{1 \cdot 3} \cdot \frac{4^2}{3 \cdot 5} \cdots \frac{(2n)^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} \cdot\frac{1}{2n+1}.
\end{align*}

Now argue that

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}
= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4k^2}} $$

converges to some non-zero real number $P$ as $n\to\infty$. (For example, take logarithm and check that the infinite series $-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\bigl(1-\frac{1}{4k^2}\bigr) $ converges.) This tells that

$$ \frac{2^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdots {(2n)}^2}{3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdots {(2n+1)}^2} \sim \frac{P}{2n+1}, $$

as $n\to\infty$ hence the series diverges by the limit comparison test with the harmonic series.